# Why is the default update rate for costmap2d only 5Hz, not the sensor rate?

Tags: navigation, costmap-2d-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The default costmap configuration in the ROS navigation stack updates the costmap every 200ms (at 5Hz). I wonder why it is not updated at the sensor's rate, or at least at the local planners rate (which is 10Hz by default). Wouldn't this make the robot react faster to new obstacles?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217821/why-is-the-default-update-rate-for-costmap2d-only-5hz,-not-the-sensor-rate?/) by [ingo](https://answers.ros.org/users/23822/ingo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2015-09-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's a tradeoff of reaction time and amount of work. The time required to update the costmap does not scale exactly linearly with the amount of sensor data. Updating more frequently involves overhead. You are free to configure it to be faster.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2015-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ingo](https://answers.ros.org/users/23822/ingo/) on 2015-09-21**:
I guessed it is to reduce work, but I've been wondering about this particular number. Did anybody do experiments and/or optimizations to arrive at the figure of 5Hz, or is it just a number chosen from experience?

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2015-09-21**:
The general rule for the nav stack is that the decisions were made to fit the PR2.